# Alternatives suggestions to apples and bananas

Tags: substitutions, fruit, allergy

As you are aware, lots of recipes call for apples, applesauce, bananas but I am severely allergic to them.  Do any of you know of alternatives for these healthy alternatives?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Could you give us more information such as if you are allergic to other fruits in the same families. E.g., pears are a great substitute for apples but they are in the same family and someone could possibly be allergic to them also. More info will help us give you a better answer.

Comment: Hello Jennifer! I'm sorry to hear about your allergy. But it is impossible to give a real answer to the question as stated. A substitute which will work in one recipe or dish won't work in another. If you are cooking or baking something specific, feel free to ask about it. You are welcome to ask multiple questions too. But we cannot cover dozens of uses for three different ingredients in a single question.

Comment: To be fair, there are a lot of things where the same substitutes would work. If you can just give some categories of things you're making (smoothies? pie/cobbler/crumble? chunks of apple in a cake or quick bread?) that'd help a lot. It'd still be better to ask about apples in one question, applesauce in another, and bananas in another, though.

Answer (score 4):

For an applesauce substitute you could make any other fruit sauce using the same method as you would make homemade applesauce - pear sauce, peach sauce, etc. In my experience applesauce is always a bit of a variable in recipes depending on if its store bought or homemade given the different sugar and water content. Baked goods made with homemade applesauce turn out sweeter and have this wonderful soft sticky crust. This happens because I cook down my applesauce, thus increasing the sugar content.

Along the same line I would use a very reduced fruit sauce for a banana substitute for baking. Bananas have tons of sugar in them, so the high sugar content is ideal.

With either replacement you should play around with how much you cook down your fruit sauce and experiment with different fruits. Water and sugar content of fruit is never exact by recipe standards, so you shouldn't have too much of an issue swapping fruits.

If bananas are primarily used raw as a sweetener, like in smoothies, try dates which have a similar sweetness.